# What really happen to loaded data when the app becomes in background

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to IOS development. I am still confused about data lifecycle inside the UIViewController. If I had a property called "userData" and I identified it as following

```
let userData : UserData! {
 didSet {
 // do something
}
}
```

and I used this data to handle click events later. What could happen if the app went to background then -say after 1 hour- the user reopened the app and found the page still displaying the content, then he clicked a button inside page. I am not sure if userData will be kept or the page lost it when it went to background!?

My app crashes when I come later and open it, but I am not sure if that's because of identifying variables like this or not

Comment: If you have a question about a crash, then update your question to ask about the crash. Post (as text) the complete and exact error message. Post relevant code causing the crash and point out the exact line causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The term background is confusing. Apple generally uses it to mean a state where your app is still getting processor time but another app is front-most. You have to ask if you want more than a few seconds of background time when the user hits the home button.

If the user presses the home button and then swaps to another app your app gets a few seconds of background time to save it's state, and then it moves to the "suspended" state, where it is still in memory, but no longer gets processor time.

Once you've been suspended, if the user switches back to your app while it's still in memory you get a resume message and then you continue running, with everything that was in memory still in memory.

However, once you've been suspended your app can be terminated at any time after that without any warning. That's why you have to save your app state when you get suspended.

If you do get terminated then the next time the user selects your app you get re-launched. You are usually expected to restore state and make it look like the app simply picked up where it left off, but it is a cold launch.

If you are crashing after your app is resumed (not terminated) then you might need help debugging that crash.